# schools of thought vs. schools of thoughts

Tags: grammatical-number

I am wondering if I should say *schools of thought* or *schools of thoughts*? The word thought can both be countable or uncountable, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**school(s) of thought**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/172522?redirectedFrom=school%20of%20thought#eid221402328) a phrase

> b. school of thought: a particular belief or way of thinking; (esp.
>   in earlier use) a group of people identified by this.

School or Schools as the word school is countable in this phrase.

As in:

> - *Guardian Weekly* With two **schools of thought** existing in France on the subject of Russia, Molotoff's speech,..has produced two 
>     different sets of reactions.

and

> - *Atlantic Monthly* American political realism—the **school of thought** that places national self-interest above idealistic schemes
>     for    social reform.

Comment: Why don’t people say ‘schools of thoughts’ then?

Comment: Because _thought_ in _schools of thought_ doesn't refer to individual thoughts, but to the category of school it is. It's a _school of thought_, like a _school of law_; both contain multiple parts, but as @lbf said, _school_ is the countable part and therefore gets any plural inflection.